# Prevent function from running if form input "required" not met

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to stop the function "load_template" from firing off , even though the input fields are blank. I get a quick error when i click submit button in for input fields , then the function is triggered. How can i stop the function from firing when input is not filled out.

I tried this but didn't work

```
document.getElementById('leaguesubmitform').onsubmit= function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

here is html and function

```
<form id="leaguesubmitform">
 <label for="leagueName">Input 1 Label</label>
 <input type="text" id="setName" placeholder="Enter League Name" name="leagueName" required>
 <label for="established">Input 1 Label</label>
 <input type="text" id="yearEst" placeholder="Enter Year Established" name="established" required>

 <input type="submit" onclick="return setLeaguename()" value="Continue">
</form>


    function setLeaguename() {
      svgLeaguename = document.getElementById("setName").value;
      yearEstablished = document.getElementById("yearEst").value;
      setTimeout("load_template()", 500);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't solely rely on the HTML `required` attribute to prevent your form submission. [It's not 100% supported](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_htmlinputelement_required) and can be bypassed quite easily anyway. Validate your form inputs manually on both the front and back end.

With that said, your code which is supposed to block submission is not working because you have to return false if you don't want the form to submit.

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", checkSubmit);

function checkSubmit(event)
{
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form action="/">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

---

For your example, it looks like you're trying to only run your `setLeaguename()` function if your two inputs are populated. Rather than putting `return setLeaguename()` in your `onclick` on your submit, validate your inputs in the form's `onsubmit` and then call `setLeaguename()` if your inputs are populated.

Here's an example using your code. I've stripped the `required` attribute just for testing purposes, as it will likely block the submission anyway. Again, it's not 100% supported and can be easily bypassed, but on modern browsers that will prevent your form submission.

```js
document.querySelector("#leaguesubmitform").addEventListener("submit", checkSubmit);

function checkSubmit(event)
{
  event.preventDefault();
  if(document.getElementById("setName").value.length > 0 && document.getElementById("yearEst").value.length > 0)
    setLeaguename();
  else
    console.log("not filled out");
    
  return false;
}

function setLeaguename() {
  var svgLeaguename = document.getElementById("setName").value;
  var yearEstablished = document.getElementById("yearEst").value;
  setTimeout("load_template()", 500);
}

function load_template()
{
  console.log("Pass");
}
```

```html
<form id="leaguesubmitform">
 <label for="leagueName">Input 1 Label</label>
 <input type="text" id="setName" placeholder="Enter League Name" name="leagueName">
 <label for="established">Input 1 Label</label>
 <input type="text" id="yearEst" placeholder="Enter Year Established" name="established">

 <input type="submit" value="Continue">
</form>
```

Comment: Even better: avoid using inline JS and use `Element.addEventListener` instead

Comment: Fair enough. Changed.

Comment: Your canIuse cite for required is completely incorrect. Look at the details it pulls up for SVG tests. That attribute works in all modern browsers

Comment: I updated it to grab the specific one for the input attribute rather than just the search results.

Comment: still not working , function load_template(); keep firing off when no text in input fields. Can you write answer using my example , maybe i'm missing something...

Comment: @MShack See my edit for another example using your code.